# Moving something that is in scope of a reference when those references will go out of scope immediately after the move

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust coming from a C++ background. I am writing a parser that reads valid formulas such as `12 x (y - 4)` and puts them in an abstract syntax tree (AST). I use an enum to store the possible nodes in the AST as you can see in the (heavily simplified) code. I ran into a problem. I want to simplify the expression `-(-(12))` for instance by **moving** the 12, not copying. In general the 12 may be replaced by a deep AST. Currently I identify the situation in the function `simplify( .. )` but it wont compile.

I do know why it doesn't compile: The node I'm trying to move (i.e. the 12 in my example) is still in scope as a reference from in the match clause so this is exactly rust preventing me from a possible problem with references. But in my case I know this is what I want, and moreover I exit the function right after I do the moving in the line `*node = **child;`, so the earlier references will go out of scope right there.

Is there an idiomatic Rust-esque type of way to solve this problem? I would really rather not copy the double--negated subtree.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Node {
    Num(i32),
    UnaryMinus(Box<Node>),
}

use Node::*;

fn simplify(node: &mut Node) {
    match &node {
        Num(_) => (),
        UnaryMinus(inner) => match &**inner {
            Num(_) => (),
            UnaryMinus(child) => {
                // cannot move out of `**child` which is behind a shared reference
                *node = **child;
                return;
            }
        },
    }
}

fn main() {
    let double_minus = UnaryMinus(Box::new(UnaryMinus(Box::new(Num(12)))));
}
```

Comment: I've not fully reasoned through it, so correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this _is_ actually sound. When you move `**child` into `*node`, `*node` gets dropped, recursively dropping everything inside it. If `child` was itself a `Box`, Rust would eventually try to drop it even though it isn't there anymore because it's been moved somewhere else.

Comment: @isaactfa Thanks for your comment. I think you're likely right, so this is indeed a bug (that the rust compiler prevented me from making :D) But still, it should be possible to so what I'm trying... Maybe I can find some solution using shared pointers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here: The error you're getting concretely is because you're matching against `&**inner` instead of `&mut **inner`. It's never okay to move out of a shared reference, but there are circumstances (which we'll see) when it's okay to move out of a mutable one.

With that fixed, you will get the same error just about mutable references. That's because you can't move out of a mutable reference just because you know you're the only one holding it. A move leaves its source uninitialized, and a reference, mutable or shared, to uninitialized memory is never okay. You'll have to leave something in that memory that you're moving out of. You can do that with `std::mem::swap`. It takes two mutable references and swaps out the contents.

Now, one could obviously try to call `std::mem::swap(node, &mut child)` but this won't work simply because `node` is already mutably borrowed in the `match` expression and you can't mutably borrow something twice.

Moreover, this would leak memory as you now have a reference cycle where `node -> inner -> node`. This, although perfectly valid to do in Rust, usually isn't what you want.

Instead you'll need some sort of dummy that you can put in `child`'s place. Some simple variant of your enum that can be safely dropped by `inner` once it gets dropped. In this example that could be `Node::Num(0)`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Node {
    Num(i32),
    UnaryMinus(Box<Node>),
}

// This is just to verify that everything gets dropped properly
// and we don't leak any memory
impl Drop for Node {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping {:?}", self);
    }
}

use Node::*;

fn simplify(node: &mut Node) {
    // `placeholder` will be our dummy
    let (mut can_simplify, mut placeholder) = (false, Num(0));
    match node {
        Num(_) => (),
        // we'll need to borrow `child` mutably later, so we have to
        // match on `&mut **inner` not `&**inner`
        UnaryMinus(inner) => match &mut **inner {
            Num(_) => (),
            UnaryMinus(ref mut child) => {
                // move the contents of `child` into `placeholder` and vice versa
                std::mem::swap(&mut placeholder, child);
                can_simplify = true;
            }
        },
    }
    if can_simplify {
        // now we can safely move into `node`
        *node = placeholder;
        // you could skip the conditional if all other, non-simplifying
        // branches return before this statement
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut double_minus = UnaryMinus(Box::new(UnaryMinus(Box::new(Num(12)))));
    simplify(&mut double_minus);
    println!("{:?}", double_minus);
}
```

Comment: FWIW for this case you could also [use `mem::replace`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=033d25e4d6ae8171bb1296ac917bad59), merging `placeholder` and `can_simplify` into a single `Option<Node>` which you can test on. You could even define `Default` on `Node`, and [use `mem::take`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fbb3710ef913564468e75f8628478811) though that's more debatable (should Node be default-able?).

Comment: With replace/take we can even make the code "flow" a hair better (in my opinion) by [returning the `Node` from the block](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c54737dbf782d0b3384734f99a01e2d) (I also used an `if let` for the inner block but I'm less convinced whether it's an improvement or not).

Comment: @Masklinn I like returning the `Node`. I could foresee a scenario where there are more expressions inside a `UnaryMinus` that you could simplify, so `if let` might not scale as well as a proper match but for this example it works great, I think.

Comment: Regarding the point about reference cycles being valid in Rust: I'm not sure they are allowed with `Box`, and there's definitely a bunch of caveats if they are. For example, if you have construct such a reference cycle and allow mutable references, that would be unsound since you could get multiple mutable references to the same data ([playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e57a547c26c6d4251a5b774abf0df414)).

Comment: @Frxstrem I didn't mean to imply I was talking about `Box` specifically, just about reference cycles which you can easily create in safe Rust.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :) What you are saying makes a lot of sense, however, the code as written will not compile for me. The compiler complains that in the inner match you are moving child out of &mut **inner, which is a mutable reference...

Comment: @Masklinn Thanks as well for your comment, that looks like a nice and clean implementation of what I was looking for

Comment: @Slugger Oh that's my bad. The inner match should read `UnaryMinus(ref mut child)` (as opposed to just `mut child`) and then `std::mem::swap(&mut placeholder, child);` (just `child` instead of `&mut child`)

Comment: @Slugger I've edited the answer so it compiles again